# Using conditions in Form Helpers of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `button_to` and `link_to` form helpers in Rails. I need to set an html attribute based on a condition in code. More precisely, I need to disable a `button_to` component only if a certain condition is true.

How can I achieve that? code snippet below.

```
<%= button_to "Submit", "#", :id=> "submit", :class => "button_white_big", :disabled => true%>
```

In above statement I may need :disabled=>true or I may not need it.
Is there a clean way, apart from duplicating the code line?

Cheers
-Priyank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace the "true" in the disabled with the condition (really any expression that returns a boolean) to get the functionality you need. Like this:

```
<%= button_to "Submit", "#", :id=> "submit", :class => "button_white_big", :disabled => obj.disabled? %>
```

or

```
<%= button_to "Submit", "#", :id=> "submit", :class => "button_white_big", :disabled => x == y %>
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

What is the condition that is true or false?

If it's triggered in the controller, you can set the disabledbutton value, or write a helper, which would take the condition as a variable, and print out the result.

`<%= button_to "Submit", "#", :id=> "submit", :class => "button_white_big", @disabled %>`

```
is_disabled? ? @disabled = {:disabled => 'disabled'} : @disabled = false
```

Comment: I tried disabled => true and false but that doesn't work. What rails generates is always :disabled => disabled

So I am not sure if true and false is an option as a value for disabled.

Comment: the :disabled option takes true or false, but the HTML either generates 'disabled="disabled"' or nothing as per the source of convert_boolean_attributes! http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/convert_boolean_attributes!